# Why Custom TabBar views are re-creating?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Extensions
extension View {
    func tabBarItem(tab: TabBarItem, selection: Binding<TabBarItem>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(TabBarItemViewModifier(tab: tab, selection: selection))
    }
}

// MARK: - Preference Keys
struct TabBarItemPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [TabBarItem] = []
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [TabBarItem], nextValue: () -> [TabBarItem]) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}


// MARK: - View Modifiers
struct TabBarItemViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let tab: TabBarItem
    @Binding var selection: TabBarItem
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.preference(key: TabBarItemPreferenceKey.self, value: [tab])
            .opacity(selection == tab ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            .disabled(selection == tab ? false : true)
    }
}

// MARK: - ViewModels
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selection: TabBarItem = .home
}


// MARK: - Content View (starting view)
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {

        CustomTabBarContainerView(selection: $viewModel.selection) {
            NavigationStack {
                HomeView()
                    .navigationTitle("Home")
            }
            .tabBarItem(tab: .home, selection: $viewModel.selection)
            
            NavigationStack {
                SecondView()
                    .navigationTitle("Second")
            }
            .tabBarItem(tab: .second, selection: $viewModel.selection)
        }
    }
}

// Custom TabBar views (container and tabbar view)
struct CustomTabBarContainerView<Content: View>: View {
    
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    private let content: Content
    @State private var tabs: [TabBarItem] = []
    @Binding private var selection: TabBarItem
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                content
            }
            CustomTabBarView(tabs: tabs, selection: $selection)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(TabBarItemPreferenceKey.self, perform: { tabs in
            self.tabs = tabs
        })
    }
    
    init(selection: Binding<TabBarItem>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content()
    }
}

struct CustomTabBarView: View {
    
    let tabs: [TabBarItem]
    @Binding var selection: TabBarItem
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                tabView(tab: tab)
                  
                    .onTapGesture {
                        switchTo(tab: tab)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tabView(tab: TabBarItem) -> some View {
        
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: tab.iconName)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
            
            Text(tab.title)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .foregroundStyle(selection == tab ? tab.color : .gray)
        
    }
    
    func switchTo(tab: TabBarItem) {
        selection = tab
    }
}


// MARK: - TabBarItem
enum TabBarItem: Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case home, second
    
    var iconName: String {
        switch self {
        case .home:
            return "house.fill"
        case .second:
            return "waveform"
        }
    }
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .home:
            return "Home"
        case .second:
            return "Second"
        }
    }
    
    var color: Color {
        Color.purple
    }
}

// MARK: - HomeView

struct HomeView: View {
    
    init() {print("HomeView init")}
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple.ignoresSafeArea().opacity(0.4)
            Text("Home view")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - SecondView
struct SecondView: View {
    
    init() {print("SecondView init")}
    
    var body: some View { Text("Second view") }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I know this is a lot of code, but I really can't figure out which part of code is relevant here. The thing is, each time I switch the tab, I have my `HomeView` and `SecondView` re-creating (aka their inits are called each time). This seems to me like some quite of a mistake in some part of my code, cause if change my custom tab bar, to native TabBar, these views don't get initialized every time, but only once. I guess I am missing here something pretty crucial?

EDIT: - Now code above is minimal reproducible example, so it can be copy/pasted to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'd prefer even more code but that copied and pasted works out of the box.

Comment: @MatBuompy I made minimal reproducible example. I think now you can just copy and run code. Let me know if something  doesn't work, but I tried  and it shows the issue.

Comment: I'll have a look later then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect SwiftUI views to be initialised many times, and should therefore not do any heavy lifting or long-running tasks inside the initaliser methods. Remember a view is just a struct, and creating and disposing of them is intentionally cheap.

I switched out your sample code for one using the standard tab bar and it also initialised each top-level view. This is normal.

The reason for this is the content of the `body` for the container view:

```swift
CustomTabBarContainerView(selection: $viewModel.selection) {
    NavigationStack {
        HomeView()
            .navigationTitle("Home")
    }
    .tabBarItem(tab: .home, selection: $viewModel.selection)
    
    NavigationStack {
        SecondView()
            .navigationTitle("Second")
    }
    .tabBarItem(tab: .second, selection: $viewModel.selection)
}
```

When the body is re-evaluated (which it would be when the selection changes), this code is run. There is nothing here to stop any line of code being executed (indeed, even if you added an if statement to the view builder, because of the way view builders work, both branches of the if statement are still executed to build a `ConditionalContent` type). This means the first and second views are both initialised.

What will *not* happen is the evaluation of the `body` of the unselected view. That won't happen until the selection changes.

This is one of the reasons that subview creation is encouraged in SwiftUI. You could have put all of the content of your home and second views right there in the tab container closure, but that would have meant the entire body of each thing was executed every time the root view was re-evaluated.

Creating views is effectively free. The individual instance of any view type is meaningless - the same view the user sees on screen is represented in SwiftUI's model by multiple instances of the type as the UI is updated. Evaluating the `body` of a view is the thing you don't want to happen for content that is not on the screen.

Comment: Actually you are right. My custom tabbar behaves the same as a native one. It was my bad. That's why I thought something is wrong with my custom implementation. That's for clarify things!

Comment: The main issue was, I tried  `TabView(selection: $viewModel.selection) {...}` vs `TabView {...}` ... In second case, actually `HomeView` and `SecondView` inits are not called after switching tabs. That got me confused...